# Why does using `<button>` as a delegate for `<input type="file">` not work, but `<a>` works in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, safari

I tried this initially in React:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    });
    const element = document.getElementById('file');
    element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
  }}
/>
<input type="file" id="file" onChange={() => alert('changed')} style="display:none">
```

This works on everything except Safari (both iOS and OSX). In Safari, the file upload dialog appears, but the `changed` alert never appears.

If I change it to this, it works in Safari:

```
<a
  href="#"
  onClick={() => {
    const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    });
    const element = document.getElementById('file');
    element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
  }}
/>
<input type="file" id="file" onChange={() => alert('changed')} style="display:none">
```

Why does `<a>` work but not `<button>`?

Comment: Is there any reason your not just doing -> `document.getElementById('file').click()`?

Comment: @Keith I tried that but it didn't work either

Comment: It might be simply adding `type="button"` to the button. Ive had issues with that before. Could you try it?

Comment: That's certainly weird. As a wild guess, perhaps it has something to do with browser focus? That an `<a>` link doesn't grab focus the way a button does?

Comment: @Alvaro `type="button"` didn't work.

Comment: @kshetline That's what I think too, because when I was searching for a solution, I came across how Safari treats focus differently.

Comment: I've got a result -- not an answer, but a result that's too complicated to post as a comment, so I'll have to post it as an "answer".

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but formatted code, so I have to post it this way.

I turned your React code into plain JavaScript and HTML, and it worked just fine in Safari for me:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Indirect file click</title>
  <script>
    function fileClick() {
      const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      });
      const element = document.getElementById('file');
      element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onClick="fileClick()">Button</button><br>
  <input type="file" id="file" onChange="alert('changed')" style="display: none">
</body>
</html>
```